# Bring Finder window to front by id?

Tags: finder, window-manager

Is it possible to bring a Finder window to the front by id? I've tried both of the following, but neither seems to work.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder" to set index of window id 120 to 1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder" to set frontmost of window id 120 to true
```

Answer (score 1):

Figures that I would stumble upon the solution to this almost immediately after posting here.

```
tell application "Finder" to set index of window id 120 to 1
```

I guess involving "System Events" when trying to use a window id retrieved via a `tell application "Finder"` statement was the problem.